# How to compare sales by region using bar chart using R

Tags: r, bar-chart, transpose

I have three variables in my data That is Region, sales2015 and sales2016. I am unable to plot bar chart for this. Tried different code but not getting desire result.

My data is data frame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbPw8.png)
[image]

Comment: What is the format of your data? Can you produce a small reproducible example?

Comment: @Titoo data should be transposed to get desired bar plot

Comment: @AdamWaring data is in csv format and data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Data

Region  Sale year   Amount
Asia    TotalSales2005  100
Asia    TotalSales2006  200
Africa  TotalSales2005  150
Africa  TotalSales2006  300
America TotalSales2005  200
America TotalSales2006  400


ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=Region, y=Amount, fill=Sale.year)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+ geom_text(aes(label=Amount))
```

[image]

Comment: my data has three variables Region, Sales2015 & Sales2016 and Sales2015 & Sale2016 have amount in it. I tried to transpose by t(data) but not getting desired result. Could you please let me know how I transpose data.

Comment: @Titoo please inset your data as text, we can't process image data

Comment: Region Sales2015 Sales2016
West 0                13208.52
West 10500.78         23114.91
East         0                 6627
East 19881 13254
East      3684.48      0
East      0                      10525.24
East     2631.31      42812.62
North   4153.89      3918.77
North -1933      6951.86
Central 2333     -1569.3
Central 11522.85      3475.93
West 0              3128.34
North 33160.3      25026.72

Comment: @Titoo please paste the same code in your post above

Comment: I am not able to paste the data

Answer (score 1):

The above answer provides the way to plot your data. To get it to the data in a desired format to use this code below:

```
library(tidyr)
df = gather(df, key = "salesyear", value = "sales", 2:3)
```

Comment: Great. Now you have your solution consider accepting an answer.